# Retrieving categories on every page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `main.blade.php` which contains my layout. As part of this layout, I need to show the categories from the database.

I would like to avoid doing the `Eloquent` call in every single controller.

How can I retrieve all categories to show on `main.blade.php` regardless of the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the base controller or the view layout you have.

In the view it would be:

```
@foreach(Category::all() as $category
```

and for a base controller, it would be *something* like:

```
$this->layout->categories = Category::all();
```

Hope this helps!

http://laravel.com/docs/templates

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to call single action in template right? :)

You can check this [package](https://github.com/DeSmart/laravel-layout) (check out [layout facade section](https://github.com/DeSmart/laravel-layout#layout-facade)). Hope it helps.